# Create,Move Between Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Powerautomate Flow help: I have a ClientID List, This list has a column called Status with 3 options (Active,Inactive,Graduates) When a Client is added They get a unique ClientID, and they are marked Active. I want to copy the ClientID from the column ClientID (in the ClientID list) over to a List called Active Clients.

When a Client gets marked Inactive on the ClientID list , I want to Move all the Clients data fields From the Active Clients list to a List called Inactive Clients, and if a client gets marked as Graduate I want to move the Clients data fields from Active Clients to a list called Graduates.

I have watched a number of videos and read articles on how to accomplish just the first step and I'm not getting it. Can anyone help point me in the right direction on this flow

I have tried when a new file is created or modified, Get Item , added multiple arrays to look for Active,Inactive,Graduate, create Item... always get an error and I think its in the Since* input

Comment: I'd like to check with you the conditions of your stream trigger: Is the status of the newly added user active? Or do you first add a user to get the ClientID, and then manually change the status of the user to active?

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor architecture IMO. Any time you are stuck duplicating data you're introducing potential for problems. Just create three views on the Clients list.

The only reason I can think of that you might want to move data around like this is if there are different security requirements for each status.